# Compressor hose line

Tags: compressor, hose, air-compressor

Would having a 20m hose connecting my compressor shed to my workshop be ok? I was planning to have the hose outside the problem is temperature differences at day and night and rain and things like that, and also UV light. Would having it inside these things protect it?
[image]

What about these electrical tubes for wires?

[image]

Could I use this one??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively easy to find UV resistant compressor hose from many manufacturers. It's also important to note the "resistant" aspect of the description. Solar UV is quite destructive and I doubt any manufacturer would consider the product to be UV proof.

Encasing your UV resistant hose in a UV opaque tube, conduit, enclosure would substantially reduce the destructive effect of the sun's UV rays. Most compressor hoses are quite durable in all temperatures and you should note that the manufacturer's specifications will include recommended temperatures. Rarely are those figures outside of human habitable levels.

I cannot comment on how to determine if an enclosure selection would be UV opaque, although black colours are usually a better choice than white and other lighter colors. I have personally observed white insulated wiring deteriorate in sunlight over a period of months, while the black insulated equivalent lasted years.

If flexibility is a requirement, one could purchase a (likely expensive) larger diameter UV resistant hose and slide the smaller working compressor hose within.

Even a selection of plumbing grade PVC will provide protection. According to this [link of somewhat limited content](http://www.commercial-industrial-supply.com/resource-center/what-are-the-effects-of-sunlight-on-pvc/), a coat of latex paint will increase the UV resistance and lifespan of ordinary PVC pipe.

Additional research shows that one can purchase specifically-UV-resistant PVC, saving the need for a coat of paint!

One more tidbit. Black polyethylene pipe can be flexible enough if needed and is available in many sizes and is quite UV resistant. Using grey PVC risks the pipe being mistaken for electrical conduit (in the USA) and is contra-indicated, despite its UV resistance.

Black PE pipe would never be mistaken for electrical and is also going to be reasonably priced, unless it is a rarity in your country.

Comment: Thank you so much fred, once again you helped me. So you think its better to buy PVC pipe than the white thing (which I dont know the name in english) to protect the hose right?

Comment: Check my edit and answer please

Comment: the third selection, black corrugated plastic, very possibly PE material, will give you good abrasion resistance and UV protection.  Painted PVC pipe would be a better choice than the rectangular molding for enclosing wire. It is likely that the white molding is a vinyl product (as in PVC) and would need to be painted for protection from UV.

Comment: Thank you so I will choose the third one, thank you for all the help as always :) They sell 100 meters for 14 euros. Gonna see if I find less length  dont need that many

Comment: Plenty of good advice above, but have you weighed the cost of using actual hard pipe? It would outlast any flexible hose. Just be sure to add a condensate drain at the low end.